# Properly querying this JSON object

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "AT": "0",
  "DE": "0",
  "FR": "0",
  "HU": "0",
  "LU": "0",
  "NL": "0"
}
```

I'm using newtonsoft's api for my development, and I'm trying to make a query on this `JObject` to check if any of these attributes are greater than 0.

I did some queries but this one is a little difficult for me and I hope that someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `jo` is your `JObject` and all the property values can be treated as integers, you can do the following query.  (Don't worry that the values are actually represented as strings in the JSON; it will work to cast the `Value` to `int`.)

```
if (jo.Properties().Any(jp => (int)jp.Value > 0))
{
    // At least one property is greater than zero
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/McNBne